# Как получить текущий URL из WebKit View?

Tags: ios, swift

Каким образом я могу получить текущий URL из `WebKit View`?
Мне нужно переходить на другой контроллер когда URL меняется на определенный.
Каким образом можно его отлавливать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Используйте navigationAction из WKNavigationDelegate, который вызывается при смене URL в WKWebView.

Вот например:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    let webView = WKWebView()
    let startUrl = "https://www.google.com"
    let endUrl = "https://www.yandex.ru"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let url = URL(string: startUrl) else { return }
        webView.frame = view.bounds
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)     {
        if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated {
            if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
                print(url)
                if url.absoluteString == self.endUrl {
                    print("Переход")
                    // performSegue(withIdentifier: "newVC", sender: nil)
                }
            }
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }

}
```

2. Используйте KVO (как уже написал уважаемый vmchar):

Пример:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let webView = WKWebView()
    let startUrl = "https://www.google.com/"
    let endUrl = "https://www.yandex.ru/"

    var urlObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let url = URL(string: startUrl) else { return }
        webView.frame = view.bounds
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        view.addSubview(webView)

        urlObservation = webView.observe(\.url, changeHandler: { (webView, change) in
            print("New url: \(webView.url?.absoluteString ?? "")")
            if webView.url?.absoluteString == self.endUrl {
                print("Переход")
                // performSegue(withIdentifier: "newVC", sender: nil)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, как раз то что нужно 
Воспользовался 2 вариантом

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите документацию по [WkWebView.URL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415005-url) - предоставляет URL, и к тому же является KVO свойством, то есть, вы сможете подписаться на изменение значения

Comment: Спасибо за помощь